# JSLinting ES6 module: undeclared global variable (jQuery from CDN)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jslint

I'm trying to get my modules to validate with JSLint. I'm loading jQuery from a CDN and I can't figure out how to avoid the `Undeclared '$'.` error. Adding `/*global $ */` at the first line also throws a validation error, since the `/*global` directive is not supported for ES6 modules.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Check [here](http://www.jslint.com/help.html#ignore): *JSLint recognizes a small but essential subset of the module syntax.`import name from stringliteral;`* Is that what you're looking for? If no, can you post a minimal snippet of code, just for kicks?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
/**
 * @global $
 * @external {@link http://link.to.cdn/jquery.js|CDN}
 * /
```

If that doesn't work, you could try other JSDoc directives which would link that CDN to the current file.